# How to share the image in meta tag in facebook using php

Tags: sharethis

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ URL::to('assets/inner/img/logo_face_share.png')}}"/>
```

I wish to add an image in facebook using sharethis plugin.It does not take the image which i gave in meta tag image. It takes the logo used in my website. How to solve this problem.